# PyAutoGui module gives PermissionError at 2nd run

Tags: permissions, python-3.4, pyautogui

I'm writing a startup script that starts and logs in on all my applications I use daily. For this I'm using the PyAutoGui module, python 3, and another application that manages the layout of my windows on my 2 monitors.

```
def smv(username, hotkey):
    # starting application
    os.system("smv.exe")
    # it autofocuses on the username field
    pyautogui.typewrite(username)
    # (passwords are the same)
    pyautogui.typewrite("PASSWORD\n")
    # move to the window header (where title, minimize, close, etc..)
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 10, duration=0)
    # drag the window to the far right of the primary monitor (since pyautogui doesn't support multiple monitors)
    pyautogui.dragTo(1910, 20, duration=1, button="left")
    # press the hotkey that belongs to the window layout manager
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "alt", hotkey)

smv("username", "num7")
smv("username2", "num1")
```

The weird thing is that the first smv() runs perfectly fine. Application starts up, logs in, moves the window and adjusts the position/size with the hotkey.
The problem occurs when the second smv() runs. Application starts up, logs in, moves to window header, but then crashes with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
   smv("username2", "num1")
File "D:\files\PyCharm\startup\smv2.py", line 10, in start
  pyautogui.dragTo(1919, 10, duration=1, button="left")
File "d:\PortableApps\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyAutoGUI-0.9.33-py3.5.egg\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 683, in dragTo
File "d:\PortableApps\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyAutoGUI-0.9.33-py3.5.egg\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 274, in mouseDown
File "d:\PortableApps\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyAutoGUI-0.9.33-py3.5.egg\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 393, in _mouseDown
File "d:\PortableApps\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyAutoGUI-0.9.33-py3.5.egg\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied.
```

I'm cracking my brain trying to figure out why it crashes at the second run. 
I've tried using try and except blocks (no use), I've switched the order in which the application starts (num1 before num7 and vice versa), but no use (1st one runs, 2nd crashes).

I've even tried to split them up into 2 files and running it from a third "main.py" file. Its not efficient, I know, but wanted to see if it made any difference.. you guessed it: it doesn't. It still crashes on PermissionError.

Answer (score 0):

In 0.9.34, this has been fixed (or at least, the exceptions are now suppressed since the clicks still seem to work anyway). So the solution is to upgrade PyAutoGUI.